# How to launch the camera in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, video-capture, landscape-portrait

i forced my app to launch only on landscape mode instead of portrait.. On the screen i am opening cam to record a video in a UIView using AVFoundation. But its orientation is not changing as landscape.. Ideas?

```
- (void) CameraSetOutputProperties
{
//SET THE CONNECTION PROPERTIES (output properties)
AVCaptureConnection *CaptureConnection = [MovieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

//Set landscape (if required)
if ([CaptureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight; //<<<<<SET VIDEO ORIENTATION IF LANDSCAPE
    [CaptureConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];
}
}
```

//

```
- (void)initializeCamera {
captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

_previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
[_previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
  ....

if (!frontCamera) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [captureSession addInput:input];
}
if (frontCamera) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [captureSession addInput:input];
}

[captureSession startRunning];
```

Comment: Does it change orientation or does video only not change orientation ?

Comment: when i launch the app on landscape, video orientation is not right.. seems like still on portrait(top or bottom home button).. @GeneratorOfOne

Answer (score 0):

If your orientation changes but your video's orientation remains, same, then you must also change your AVCaptureConnection's videoOrientation property,

You can use that using **viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:** method as,

```
 override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
         super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        if size.width > size.height {
            capturePreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeLeft
        } else {
            capturePreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
        }
    }
```

And this should work for your case.